# how do we increasing variable count using a foreach loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a foreach loop to keep looping into the var number is reached. I also need to keep track of the index.  so far what I have tried

```
const data = ()=>{
    const myNumber = input.getPortCount() // Example currently this will be output a number 0 - 9
    foreach(i == 0, i => myNumber ++i){
         return console.log('i equals', i)
    }
}
```

I need I to increase by 1 start at 0 into it equal to the number of the variable myNumber

Comment: It seems like you are trying to do a for loop!
for (var i = 0; i < myNumber; i++) { console.log('i equals', i) }
forEach are for array looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go learn about loops. You need here the `for` loop and not `foreach`....
but you have more mistakes. here is the loop you need:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= myNumber; ++i){
     console.log('i equals', i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is syntax for `forEach` array, used on arrays :

```js
array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```